# Google Script HTML/CSS/JS code not running

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, owl-carousel

I have a bootstrapped carousel that is working within my local machine but doesn't work when I tried to implement within Google Scripts environment.

I've followed the instructions from this website, but doesn't seem to work at all: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices. In fact, when I follow these guidelines, it only shows 3 dots (part of my HTML) and nothing else. When I take out the code suggested by this guide, it shows my HTML but can't integrate with CSS or JS code.

Here is my code:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    // clearInterval( timer );
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

// Sets transition every 3 seconds
timer = setInterval( function(){
  plusSlides(1); }, 3000 );
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}

.mySlides {
  display: none}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.carousel-caption {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0,.6);

}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}

/* Transition right to left */
```

```html
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/236047/pexels-photo-236047.jpeg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Caption 1</h3>
      <p>Caption 1 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webcontent/@web/documents/media/2016-photocontest-yosemite-w-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Caption 2</h3>
      <p>Caption 2 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Caption 2</h3>
      <p>Caption 2 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- ADD ADDITIONAL IMAGES IN THE [ADD IMG ...] PART -->
  <!-- <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
    <img src="[ADD IMG ...]" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">This is for a Caption text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
    <img src="[ADD IMG] ..." style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">This is for a Caption text</div>
  </div> -->

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    <!-- <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>  -->
  </div>

</body>


<script type="text/javascript" src="interactions.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> -->
```

This is my code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have jquery included in the solution/website ?  Is there something written in the brower's console ?

Comment: I added jquery to my code

Comment: Running that snippet throws a ReferenceError, so I imagine you need to fix that. It's not clear in your question what code you are referring to either, so please edit your question to make it explicitly clear what code you are referring to when talking about adding/removing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails, becouse you don't have jQuery. Add it to your project. Order is important!

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/yourscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: that didn't seem to fix the problem for the google scripts

Comment: the javascript functions all work fine it seems in my local environment

Answer (score 0):

jQuery should be loaded before calling `$`. Also the code misses calling some owlCarousel important files.

I took borrowed the missing files from http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ and commented out the following lines

```
$('.slideshow-container').owlCarousel({
  rtl: true
});
```

The above makes the code to apparently work fine on Stack Snippet.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    // clearInterval( timer );
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

// Sets transition every 3 seconds
timer = setInterval(function() {
  plusSlides(1);
}, 3000);

/*
$('.slideshow-container').owlCarousel({
  rtl: true
});
*/
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

.mySlides {
  display: none
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.carousel-caption {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .6);
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}


/* Transition right to left */
```

```html
<!-- Owl Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

<!-- JavaScript files -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/236047/pexels-photo-236047.jpeg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption 1</h3>
        <p>Caption 1 text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
      <img src="https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webcontent/@web/documents/media/2016-photocontest-yosemite-w-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption 2</h3>
        <p>Caption 2 text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption 2</h3>
        <p>Caption 2 text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ADD ADDITIONAL IMAGES IN THE [ADD IMG ...] PART -->
    <!-- <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
    <img src="[ADD IMG ...]" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">This is for a Caption text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
    <img src="[ADD IMG] ..." style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">This is for a Caption text</div>
  </div> -->

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    <!-- <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>  -->
  </div>

</body>



<!-- <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> -->
```